# Is there a possibility to run a component after a Http Response?

Tags: angular

I am connecting to my own API. This API returns a JSON response which contains some text with an Angular component tag like:

```
<app-heroes></app-heroes>
```

Once i output this to html file it doesn't render the component? Is there any possibility to render the component after i received the http get request? I think it was possible in AngularJs with $compile.

It does render the tag as html, but it won’t render the component.

Thanks!

Edit: I'm using version 5.1

Comment: which version of Angular are you using?

Comment: @Luillyfe Angular 5.1

Answer (score 1):

create a custom directive like this.

```
export function createComponentFactory(compiler: Compiler, metadata: Component): Promise<ComponentFactory<any>> {
    const cmpClass = class DynamicComponent {};
    const decoratedCmp = Component(metadata)(cmpClass);

    @NgModule({ imports: [CommonModule, RouterModule, SharedModule], declarations: [decoratedCmp] })
    class DynamicHtmlModule { }

    return compiler.compileModuleAndAllComponentsAsync(DynamicHtmlModule)
       .then((moduleWithComponentFactory: ModuleWithComponentFactories<any>) => {
        return moduleWithComponentFactory.componentFactories.find(x => x.componentType === decoratedCmp);
      });
}

@Directive({ selector: 'html-outlet' })
export class HtmlOutlet {
  @Input() html: string;
  cmpRef: ComponentRef<any>;

  constructor(private vcRef: ViewContainerRef, private compiler: Compiler) { }

  ngOnChanges() {
    const html = this.html;
    if (!html) return;

    if(this.cmpRef) {
      this.cmpRef.destroy();
    }

    const compMetadata = new Component({
        selector: 'dynamic-html',
        template: this.html,
    });

    createComponentFactory(this.compiler, compMetadata)
      .then(factory => {
        const injector = ReflectiveInjector.fromResolvedProviders([], this.vcRef.parentInjector);   
        this.cmpRef = this.vcRef.createComponent(factory, 0, injector, []);
      });
  }

  ngOnDestroy() {
    if(this.cmpRef) {
      this.cmpRef.destroy();
    }    
  }
}
```

Now from the component pass the html as input to the directive which you want to render

```
@Component({
  selector: 'my-home',
  template: `
    <h1>home</h1>
    <html-outlet [html]="value"></html-outlet>
  `
})
export class HomeComponent {
  value = `<app-heroes></app-heroes>`;
}
```

[Demo](https://plnkr.co/edit/TAbupH4si62x10QZ7xuc?p=preview)

Comment: Is this working with  V5.1? It unfortunately does not work in my 5.1 project. Thanks for the reply!

Answer (score 1):

Try using `innerHTML` property on a div, like:

```
<div [innerHTML]="customHTML"></div>
```

Where `customHTML` is the response of your API, for example `<app-heroes></app-heroes>`. `innerHTML` property binds HTML string inside a div

Comment: It does render the tag as html but it doesn't run the component. Thanks for the reply though!

Comment: Try adding your Logic in ngAfterViewInit() in your component, so it will be executed after the loading, performing your operations

Comment: when i click a button to loaf additional content will it still run the component?

Answer (score 0):

Getting a text from an API and display it as a component is possible but a little bit hacky and hard-coded.

Here's what I would do.

```
@Component({
  selector: 'some-component',
  template: `
     <h1> Some Component </h1>
    <app-heroes *ngIf="textToComponent  === '<app-heroes></app-heroes>'" > </app-heroes/>
  `
})
export class SomeComponent {
   constructor(){
        this.getData();
   }
  textToComponent= `<app-heroes></app-heroes>`;

//call your api here and set the textToComponent;
   getData(){
   }
}
```

What I did here is I already added the other component in the template and toggle it by using `*ngIf`. I'm not sure if that exactly what you want though.
If you want an advanced solution for this, try to look for creating dynamic component.

Also here's a [stackblitz demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-a7ktue?file=app%2Fapp.component.html) from above.